# Old OPENGL code, want to use glPushMatrix()

Tags: c++, opengl, build, cmake, libraries

1st Question!

I'm trying to compile some openGL code where I use glPushMatrix().

I plan on reformatting the code to more recent practices (because glPushMatrix is deprecated), but,for now, I'd like to use a version of (openGL, GLU, GLUT)? where this function works.

My current cmake file looks like this

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (PROJECTOR)



set( PROJECTOR_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set( PROJECTOR_VERSION_MINOR 1)

add_executable( Projector.run /*...buncha files */  )

find_package(Boost) 
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# TODO - this doesn't rollback versions. It just sets a min version requirement.
#           I'd like to roll back the versions.
find_package(OpenGL 2.0)
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(GLU)
include_directories(${GLUE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(Projector.run ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Projector.run ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Projector.run ${GLU_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Projector.run ${OpenGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Projector.run ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})
#
```

And this is the **error output**:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Projector.run.dir/open_image.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glPushMatrix'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Projector.run] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Projector.run.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And this is a **code snippet**:

```
...
glPushMatrix();

    int img_height,img_width = 3;
    int row,col = 0;


    for(col = 0; col < img_height; col++ )
    {
        for(row = 0; row < img_width; row++){

            glTranslatef(CUBE_DIMEN,0.0f,0.0f);
            glColor3f(r_comp,g_comp,b_comp);
            glutSolidCube(CUBE_DIMEN);

        }

        glTranslatef(-1 * img_width * CUBE_DIMEN, -CUBE_DIMEN, 0.0f);

    }   

    glPopMatrix();
...
```

What should I add so that my program will build?

Comment: Can you share the error message? Well, you don't explicitly say that it fails, but I figure you wouldn't post here if it worked. ;)

Comment: Your build setup has nothing to do with creating an OpenGL context. Contexts are created at runtime, so we need to see the code that creates it. If you're not asking for a core profile, then you're probably getting a compatibility context which has `glPushMatrix`.

Comment: Okay, I added more detail! Does this help?

Comment: It doesn't look like OpenGL is being linked with your program.

Comment: It's still being linked, I'm just not sure how to link to a previous version.

Comment: @user2058225 There is currently no such thing as a previous OpenGL version at link-time. A conforming OpenGL implementation will always provide the legacy functions as well as the modern ones. In other words, newer versions are backwards-compatible with older ones. It is only during runtime initialization that you can request blocking access to the legacy function by requesting a core context.

Answer (score 0):

Compile using the `-lGL` flag to include the library:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -lglut -lGL
```